# Can I use epoxy putty to patch metal?

Tags: metal, ants, epoxy

The outer "frame" of my fireplace is comprised of a thin, sheet-metal-like material that is separating at the seams in some places.  Ants are finding their way up from beneath the fireplace and making their way into my house through these broken seams.  I Googled "metal filler" and happened upon epoxy putty, one type of which is designed for higher temps in the 500 degree range.  Would I be able to fill these broken seams with this putty?  If not, what should I use?

Also, I know that ants are relentless and that many of you will say that I am wasting my time trying to keep them out.  However, I am gradually sealing off all their entry points into my house and have been successful thus far as they are forced to locate another way in.  Eventually, though, I will prevail even if it leaves me with only one arm and one leg.  I have declared war on these ants.  While I could kill the colony with ant traps, a new colony will only replace them.  My home is my fortress, and keep out the enemy I surely will.  As Bruce Campbell would say at a time like this: Come get some.

**Edit:** Per commenter's suggestion below, I came upon this product:

[image]

Comment: The metal is going to expand when the fireplace is in use and have the chance of damage/bubble (not being able to expand because of the epoxy) or crack the epoxy because of a thin application or cheap/weakened epoxy. If the metal is removable, I'd suggest removing it and filling the gap with high-temp caulking.

Comment: Good points.  See update to question.  If you have better ideas for products, please share.

Comment: As long as it doesn't actually have a flame hit it, that looks good.

Comment: JB Weld works great and is supposedly rated for car engines, so would imagine it can take the heat. I'm curious as to where the ants are coming from, though. Is the only thing separating the inside space from outside this metal panel?

Comment: @DA01 The outer "frame" of fireplace is put together by welded seams behind this vent cover.  There was a pretty big gap between the seams on one side and they were getting in through there after I blocked them off every place else.  After caulking that seam, though, I haven't seen a single ant in the area.  I kicked their collective arses.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you would go to an auto parts store and get a filler like [Bondo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003TQDJ00) .

Bondo has a pretty high heat rating and is not flammable in your conditions.  You will sand the areas, use mesh for bigger holes and apply.  You can't put this stuff on paint - it won't stick well.  And I would make sure the bonding area is rust free too.  This should be about a 2 hour job.